# Can i create a mini int class that only consist of 1, 0, -1?

Tags: java, data-structures, integer

i'will optimize and increase performance the code that is given by teacher for tic-tac-toe game. Since i'll be only use X = 1, O = -1 and EMPTY = 0, i dont want to keep these numbers in an 32bit int array. Can i create my class just like int class but only have 1, 0, -1. I want to do that;

```
public static final int X = 1, O = -1, EMPTY = 0;
myDataType[][] board = new myDataType[3][3];
board[0][0] = X;
board[0][1] = O;
```

Comment: What about `byte`?

Comment: Can you give an example of usage?

Comment: Just so I'm clear essentially you want a class to have an int value that is either 1, 0, -1?  Meaning the class will have one field that is an int value and nothing else?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use an Enum

Comment: Lucas, i want to create a data type just like ünt except pf mine will consist of  only 3 numbers 1,0,-1

Comment: Anthony can you give example

Comment: I would agree with Anthony that in this case an Enum would work, here is some examples https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enum-in-java/. A class would also work, but an enum would be more efficient.

Comment: The reference to an instance of a wrapper class would probably take even more memory.

Comment: You have 3 states per number, so one simple approach would be to store 4 of them in a single `byte` (using 2 bits for each one) - and then provide some accessor for them.  `0b11 & (number << index)` to get the state for a given index from the number.

Comment: Note: This is tic tac toe.  Assuming this is a class project then this level of micro-optimisation is _seriously_ overkill and probably not what your teacher is wanting you to take home from this.  Knowing _when_ to optimise, as well as some fundamentals is just as important as knowing _how_ to optimise.

Answer (score 1):

To answer to your question. Let's assume you can use boolean (primitive data type with simple 'b' to  for your array). In theory it should only take, 1 bit per array element. However according to java docs. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html

> In Oracle’s Java Virtual Machine implementation, boolean arrays in the Java programming language are encoded as Java Virtual Machine byte arrays, using 8 bits per boolean element.

In this case it takes 8 bits per boolean element. (This is for just for argument sake and we cannot use boolean since it only have true and false)

The next option is use Boolean Boxed type. It can hold the values true,false and null

You can map it like this,

```
true => 1,
false => -1,
null => 0
```

and Implement it like this,

```
 Boolean[][] board = new Boolean[3][3];
    board[0][0] = null;
    board[0][1] = false;
    board[1][0] = true;
```

How ever it turns out Boolean Boxed type takes 128bits in memory.(https://www.baeldung.com/java-primitives-vs-objects)

If you create a custom class, it will also take more memory. Therefore it is better to use a byte type as below, for your array like most suggested.

```
byte[][] board = new byte[3][3];
    board[0][0] = -1;
    board[0][1] = 0;
    board[1][0] = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: I'm not saying this is a good idea.  But...

---

There's only 3^9 = 19683 possible states of an *entire board* of tic tac toe.  You can easily fit this in a single `int`.  As an example of how to do that, look at it in binary, and consider each *pair* of bits as a single cell:

```java
private int state = 0b00_00_00_00_00_00_00_00_00;
```

Where we can use `00` as unset, `10` as X and `11` as O (`01` is unspecified, but call it unset too, that way it's unset if the high bit is `0`).

Then we can get/set a value by simply shifting the value to the appropriate bits of our `state`.  In this case: `( 3 * row ) + col` (to number the cells of the board) and then `*2` since we're using 2 bits for each cell.

```java
public static final int UNSET = 0b00;
public static final int X = 0b10;
public static final int O = 0b11;

public void set( final int row, final int col, final int val ) {
    state |= ( val << index( row, col ) );
}

public int get( final int row, final int col ) {
    return 0b11 & ( state >>> index( row, col ) );
}

private static final int index( final int row, final int col ) {
    return 2 * ( ( 3 * row ) + col );
}
```

Where we use OR to set the values at a specific bits, and use AND to mask the result to the two bits we're interested in.  Some validation would probably be good here (check `row` and `col` are in bounds, check `val` is between `0b00` and `0b11`, check the cell is unset before setting, whatever else).

---

With this, then say the first player goes in the middle (with X), your state would be:

```java
state = 0b00_00_00_00_10_00_00_00_00_00;
```

Then the next player goes top-left with an O:

```java
state = 0b00_00_00_00_10_00_00_00_00_11;
```

etc.

---

Again, I'm not saying this is a good idea, or will be any faster for you, or understandable for people quickly reading through the code...  But it'll store the whole board in a single int rather than an array of them :shrug:.

Comment: Note: you could do this with a [ternary system](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_numeral_system) and store it in a `short`. But without extra work for reading the value (either by recursive division, or a sequence of 8 subtractions) I suspect this would be slower as the ‘bit shift to get’ step would be far more complex (there’s no ‘trit shift’ operator).